# Density-Based Clustering Validation (DBCV) never stops running

Tags: cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have completed running DBSCAN on a dataset of mine clustering patches of deforestation and I am attempting to validate the results according to [this paper.](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611973440.96)

I have install the package from this [Github,](https://github.com/christopherjenness/DBCV) but when I try and run the code it never completes. I ran it for over a 5 days and it never stopped running or threw an error. Running DBSCAN only took 15 minutes so I am a little confused why just the validating is taking so long. Is there something I'm getting wrong with the DBCV code or the inputs?

Since it never finishes running the code I don't know of an error that I can report. I am unsure if I'm inputting the data into the code correctly, but I tried to copy the example on GitHub as closely as I could. I don't know how to share my .csv file to show what my file is like. It has 16 dimensions that I consense down using a MinMaxScaler before running DBSCAN. I have previously completed the DBSCAN clustering and an just trying to get the DBCV to work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pylab import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import sklearn
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from scipy.spatial import euclidean
from DBCV import DBCV

f = pd.read_csv('csv_file_I_Don't_know_how_to_share')
x = f.loc[:, [1-15]].values

norm_data = MinMaxScaler()
data = norm_data.fit_transform(x)

dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=.15, min_samples = 100)
clusters = dbscan.fit_predict(data)

DBCV_score = DBCV(data, clusters, dist_function=euclidean)

print ('DBCV Score: ' + DBCV_score)
```

I'm expecting a score to be printed but instead the code continues to run and doesn't stop. Any help would be great!

Comment: Maybe that is just a very slow implementation? Have you tried **other implementations of DBCV**? You know: not all code on github (nor SO) ist good... If it fails to work, you better go try another...

Comment: I fell into the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You run:

```py
from scipy.spatial import euclidean
```

But the [code on GitHub](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html) defines the method to use euclidean imported like this:

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
```

Try changing this, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @Dumbfool there seems to be an error in:
`print('DBCV Score: ' + DBCV_score)`

Try changing the `+` to `,`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, after all above considered correct, with DBSCAN.
DBCV works with HDBSCAN like specified here: [Requirements](https://github.com/christopherjenness/DBCV/blob/master/requirements.txt)

Furthermore, still there is not a valid package to calculate this value. By doing some searchings I found that it's well-known the slowness.
You can try with a smaller df, like 1k records or less (one column is faster). Otherwise visual check is one of the best options.

EDIT:
I found this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980972/lower-dbcv-scores-for-cluster-analysis-using-sklearns-gridsearchcv) and seems authour is using a validity function to do what you want. Maybe if you can install this package

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan
```

with success, you can try if it works in reasonably time.